# InfoPath 2010 publish issues; resolved with reboot

Tags: sharepoint-2010, publish, infopath2010

I receive the following error message about 50% of the time when trying to publish an InfoPath 2010 form template to my corporate SharePoint site:

[image: Publish_Error_Image]

The image text reads:

`Infopath canot save the following form: https://sharepoint.site.com/home/subsite/form_library
This document library was either renamed or deleted, or network problems are preventing the file from being saved. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator.`

The thing that is odd about this is that I can resolve the problem by rebooting my system and reauthenticating to the site. I am then able to republish my template at least once.

Things I have tried:

1. Clearing my SSL state in Internet Explorer, reauthenticating to SharePoint in the browser
2. Starting InfoPath from the run prompt with the following switches: `infopath /cache clearall`
3. Rebooting (always fixes the issue - would like to avoid this)

My corporate SharePoint site sits on a different domain than my desktop. This could be an issue here, but I don't know why it would persist after reauthenticating.

This topic may fit more neatly on the SharePoint SE site, but the potential for networking related problems made me feel the need to post it to SO.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was able to resolve by closing out of IP and then bringing up Task Manager and killing a still living IP process.  Opening IP and republishing.  No reboot required.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I changed jobs so I can't test it at this point. But I'll give you an upvote! I hope others can confirm this fix :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because the Desktop Experience feature is not enabled on the Windows Server 2008 R2 server. Therefore, connections cannot be made from the Windows Server 2008 R2 server to the SharePoint server.

Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752612